# Compare two object lists with LINQ on specific property

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have these two lists (where the *Value* in a *SelectListItem* is a bookingid):

```
List<SelectListItem> selectedbookings;
List<Booking> availableBookings;
```

I need to find the ids from `selectedBookings` that are not in `availableBookings`. The LINQ join below will only get me the bookingids that are in `availableBookings`, and I'm not sure how to do it the other way around.

`!=` won't work since I'm comparing strings.

```
results = (
  from s in selectedbookings
  join a in availableBookings on s.bookingID.ToString() equals a.Value
  select s);
```

Comment: What makes you think that `!=` won't work due to using strings? (You can't do a join in an exclusive fashion, but that's got nothing to do with strings...)

Comment: I tried with `=` and it said that *`a` was not in the scope on the left side of equals*. I presumed it had something to do with the `=` sign.

Comment: Right, that's because `join` always uses `equals` to indicate the two parts - but again, that's got nothing to do with strings.

Comment: Ah, of course. Bad reasoning...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I need to find the ids from selectedBookings that are not in availableBookings.

That's easy - it's all the IDs in selected bookings *except* those that are in available bookings:

```
var ids = selectedBookings.Select(x => x.bookingID.ToString())
                          .Except(availableBookings.Select(x => x.Value));
```

Or perhaps more readably:

```
var selectedIds = selectedBookings.Select(x => x.bookingID.ToString());
var availableIds = availableBookings.Select(x => x.Value);
var result = selectedIds.Except(availableIds);
```

Comment: Thank you, I prefer the compact version though.

Comment: @Niklas: You mean the first one? That's fine - the second was really just trying to unpack that in case you had problems understanding it.